# Scale and Precision from Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to get the scale and precision from a number in the following example.

`var x = 1234.567;`

I'm not seeing any `.scale` or `.precision` functions built in and I'm not sure what the best way to right one is.

Comment: What are those scale and precision ? Do you mean the numbers of digits on each side of the point ?

Comment: convert to a string and then do split and see the string length.

Comment: Does that make any sense with floating point? Consider `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1`. You'd expect that to be `0.3`. Well it's not. It's `0.30000000000000004`. Suddenly, your precision has shot up.

Comment: @Eric He doesn't use the numbers for calculation.

Comment: @VisioN: Even so, there are floating point problems here. If you're not going to use numbers to calculate, store them as a string!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 1234.567;

var parts = x.toString().split('.');

parts[0].length; // output: 4 for 1234

parts[1].length; // output: 3 for 567
```

#### NOTE

Javascript has **[toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)** method that gives to a number with specified length.

For example:

```
var x = 1234.567;

x.toPrecision(4); // output: 1234

x.toPrecision(5); // output: 1234.5

x.toPrecision(7); // output: 1234.56
```

But

```
x.toPrecision(5); // output: 1235

x.toPrecision(3); // output: 1.23e+3
```

and so on.

#### According to comment

Is there a way to check that the string contain `.`?

```
var x = 1234.567

x.toString().indexOf('.'); // output: 4
```

#### Note

`.indexof()` return first index of target else `-1`.

Comment: Precision should be the entire length minus the ., I'm assuming once you convert it to a string you would remove the . and get the length? Excellent way to get the before and after though. Is there a good way to determine if the string contains the . before running the script?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
var x = 1234.56780123;
    
x.toFixed(2); // output: 1234.57
x.toFixed(3); // output: 1234.568
x.toFixed(4); // output: 1234.5680
```

Answer (score 3):

Another advanced solution (if I correctly understand what you mean by *scale* and *precision*):

```
function getScaleAndPrecision(x) {
    x = parseFloat(x) + "";
    var scale = x.indexOf(".");
    if (scale == -1) return null;
    return {
        scale : scale,
        precision : x.length - scale - 1
    };
}

var res = getScaleAndPrecision(1234.567);

res.scale;       // for scale
res.precision;   // for precision
```

If number is not float function returns `null`.

Comment: What would you recommend when a number contains more than a single decimal point?

Comment: example 123.456.7, I see for precision you are subtracting -1 when you see the decimal which would cause the true precision length to be off. Just wondering what your thoughts were on this.

Comment: @George how is it possible that a number contains more that one decimal point?

Comment: @George It is impossible in JavaScript (and in other programming languages I know) to have a **number** with two or more decimal points.

Comment: I understand where your coming from, however I'm accepting values from input fields which could come across as strings. I think I just need to do a type check to be sure it's a number and not a string.

Comment: IP addresses have multiple decimal points but are not actually numbers. Aside from that, I can't think of any situation multiple decimal points need to be handles.

Comment: @George Then we can include "the trimmer" of possible problems that come from the input field. I used `parseFloat`, check it in the updated answer.

Comment: @George values accepting from input field will always treat as string

Comment: You guys are right, I'm adding a new validator to an existing validation project and some wheres in the js logic it converts the type before being passed into my new method, ie it could come to me a string. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I feel like he explained what was actually going on a little bit better, however you showed me how to get the precision.

Comment: @VisioN we have nothing to say about OP's choice, I think, I think your solution was so good

Comment: I like both and used both, both are great answers, but unfortunately you can only select one as the best answer and I just felt thecodeparadox did a nice job providing explanations to the different pieces of code which will ultimately help others in the future. I appreciate both of your help because at the end of the day, my problem has been resolved.

Comment: I personally think this solution is great and exactly what I needed, despite all the comments...