# RegEx for range between 1-999999 and precision upto 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I trying trying to apply RegEx in JavaScript that will allow user to enter ammount of min 1 and max 999999 and if user want to enter ammount in decimal then it will allow user to enter decimal upto precision of 2.

Below are the inputs with their respective result

```
100: Pass
999999: Pass
100.23: Pass
100.2: Pass
100.234: Fail
```

This is what I have tried so far `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|999999)$)`, this allow me to enter the amount within 1-999999 but I also want to handle decimal cases.

Comment: First of all checking numeric ranges with regex is usually frowned upon. Your current regex doesn't do what you say it does, e.g. it'll fail on `1000`. Is `999999.99` valid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if this is an answer, please post it as answer...

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions when a simple check (`number >= 0 && number <= 999999`) would do the same thing, but much more easily (and clearly)?

Comment: but @DavidThomas, what if user enters 100.234? I also want to handle decimal cases

Comment: @DavidThomas because the OP doesn't want a decimal precision greater than two places. I guess?

Comment: @evolutionxbox To check the precision, we can convert the number a String, split it on `.` and can validate, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10952926/6048928

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for checking decimal precision, too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work?:

`^[1-9]\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing it logically;

```js
[0, 0.75, 100, 999999, 999999.75, 100.23, 100.2, 100.234].forEach(i => {
  var inRange = i >= 1 && i <= 999999; // check whether in range 1-999999
  var inPrecisionRange = i * 100 % 1 == 0;  //check whether has at most 2 dec. point
  console.log(i + " -> " + (inRange && inPrecisionRange));
});
```

Much simpler, easier to read and much more maintainable than RegEx IMO

Comment: using `>= 1` would be better; if input = `0.55` , it's in your range but not in 1-99.. .